# ASP.Net page or handler to load mp3/avi and send to browser - BOTH internal file path and external url as source

Tags: c#, asp.net, filesystems, streaming, mp3

So there are many examples of getting the stream from a file locally, but suppose i want to stream an MP3 from another site.

I have a page that lists urls of MP3s, for example, one might be...

> www.domain.com/getResource.aspx?ResourceId=123

This page can obviously fairly simply load Resource 123, and send to the browser.

Suppose resource 123 is **not local**, it is a URL to another site which serves up the mp3

so my question is what is the best way for this Resource Page to get the data from the remote source and send back to the browser. In effect, there should be no differential as far as the client is concerned where the file has come from. It always goes through this aspx (or ashx) page

Comment: you mean the url redirects you to new url with the resource.. is that the question

Comment: You should just be able to redirect (Response.Redirect) to the new location. This is fairly common practice when assets such as music and video files are hosted elsewhere. Not sure what mp3 player you're using but it will need to support redirects. So why do you want to get the resource to your server only to stream it out. If you're paying for bandwidth you'll be paying twice, not to mention the delay caused by this.

Answer (score 0):

Your site would need to make its own HTTP request to the remote server.  Take the content of the response, and write it to the response stream of the request that came to your site.

Comment: It seems response.redirect(mp3Url) seems to work, is this likely to be unreliable cross browser? I was surprised this worked as it is a component on the page taking the input (a media player) but it seems to have handled the redirect...

Comment: How would this be done? Do you have any code snippets or anything? While response.redirect seems to work, i seems like it **might** be something that is unreliable across browsers running the Media Player

Comment: If Response.Redirect is working, then it will likely work in all browsers.  If you don't want to do the redirect, then use the `HttpWebRequest` class to create a request, then use the `GetResponse` method to actually send the request and wait for the response.  Once you have the response, call `GetResponseStream` then read from that stream and write to the response stream of the request your server is currently handling.